# Python variable weird issue

Tags: python

sorry i really do not know how to describe this issue accurately in the title

I define a function like this

```
def f(v,l=[]):
    l.append(v)
    return l
```

In my understanding, the output should be like this:

the first call should return [0]

the second call should return [1]

the third call should return [2]

But.. here is the real output

```
>>> f(0)
[0]
>>> f(1)
[0, 1]
>>> f(2)
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: don't use `l=[]`  because Python creates this `[]` only once when script is loaded.

Comment: To be more precise, default arguments are evaluated when the function definition is executed, not when the function is called.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do

```
def f(v, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = []
    l.append(v)
    return l
```

because in `l=[]` this list `[]` is created only once when script is loaded.

More precise (as @PM2Ring said) it is created when the function definition is executed, not when the function is called.

See: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/